# Sentence structure: how to combine the sentence together?

Tags: word-order, sentence-patterns, syntactic-analysis

I was writing this in my paper.

> 70 million photos and videos are sent daily on Instagram, while Louvre
>   Museum has 300,000 objects [Kaplan and Haenlein, 2010], which is
>   merely 0.4% of Instagram in quantity.

But the sentence seems long and the structure is weird. I think I should combine Louvre's object and percentage in one sentence, but I'm not sure how to rephrase it.

Could you please help me rephrase it? Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately proofreading questions are off-topic for this site, which may result in closure of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding. One quick question, does the sentence structure seen okay to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The** Louvre Museum **merely** has 300,000 objects [Kaplan and Haenlein, 2010] all told, 0.4% of the 70 million photos and videos sent on Instagram daily.